# How do I configure NodeRestriction plug-in on kubelet?

Tags: security, kubernetes, kubelet, kube-apiserver, hardening

### Let's start with some context:

I'm studying CKS and reading CIS_Kubernetes_Benchmark_v1.6.0.pdf and there's a confusing section:

```
1.2.17 Ensure that the admission control plugin NodeRestriction is set (Automated) 

...
Verify that the --enable-admission-plugins argument is set to a value that includes 
NodeRestriction. 
  
Remediation: 
Follow the Kubernetes documentation and configure NodeRestriction plug-in on kubelets. 
Then, edit the API server pod specification file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-
apiserver.yaml on the master node and set the --enable-admission-plugins parameter 
to a value that includes NodeRestriction.
```

The part about check if `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml` has an entry for - `--enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction`,... makes sense, the annoying part is
`"Follow the Kubernetes documentation and configure NodeRestriction plug-in on kubelets."`
Is extremely hard to google, and the Kubernetes official docs aren't clear about how to do this.

### So now that the context is there the question is:

After setting - `--enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction` on the kube-apiserver, how do you verify that the NodeRestriction plug-in on the kubelet has been correctly configured?

Answer (score 1):

To properly enable NodeRestrictions Admission Controller Plugin, you actually need to update kubernetes configuration in 3 different places:

1. kube-apiserver: - `--enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction,...`
2. kube-apiserver: - `--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC`   (You must have Node specified)
3. kubelet (of every node): `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`  should have `authorization.mode: Webhook` (Other kubernetes distributions may substitute `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` with another method of configuring it, but I'm sure there'd be a matching value)

When kubelet's authorization.mode is set to Webhook, instead of it's default of `AlwaysAllow`, it offloads authorization decisions to the kubernetes api-server. The Node Authorization mode is a special-purpose authorization mode that specifically authorizes API requests made by kubelet.

(The giantswarm article below is a great read, and does a good job explaining why you should implement this setting, I'll try to summarize it by saying that's generic hardening that helps prevent privilege escalation by a compromised workload or bad actor.)

Sources:
1.) [Kubernetes Security Essentials (LFS260)](https://training.linuxfoundation.org/training/kubernetes-security-essentials-lfs260/)
2.) [Securing the Configuration of Kubernetes Cluster Components](https://www.giantswarm.io/blog/securing-the-configuration-of-kubernetes-cluster-components)
3.) [Using Node Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/node/)